# Horrid Graphics Glitches

Tags: drivers, graphics, 15.10, intel-graphics

My system , a homebuilt with a GMA 950 and 1GB RAM , has being having graphics problems ever since installation . For example , once I was using Android Studio (for some reason this *always* happens when I use Android Studio) and the screen turned this way. [image: screen weird]

I cannot switch to tty's and restart lightdm , I used to do this when crashed of a lesser magnitude happened . Now all I can do is press reset . And that is not good for my system . Many other posters have said its caused by the graphics driver acceleration . I notice , when I get lesser magnitude crashes and can switch to tty1 , that

```
    $ dmesg|tail
```

says something about the graphics card hanging and Xorg resetting it . Is this a graphics driver issue ? I notice this does not happen in elementary OS on another parttiton , or Windows 7 (though both have other problems).

Answer (score 0):

1GB RAM?

There's your problem. Android studio *requires* at least 2GB RAM.

Also the Intel GMA graphics are terrible.

Comment: I think I fixed it though . What I did was , in `\usr\share\X11\xorg.conf.d` , I added a file called 20-intel.conf and filled so it would use `uxa` for acceleration